# Mongodb filter out Date() and ISODate() from same field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema for the date field

```
startDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
```

Somehow this field have 2 different value like this

`Date(29906992800000)` and `ISODate("2022-05-31T03:23:32.193-06:30")`

Now I am trying to filter out **Date(...)** to convert to **ISODate(...)**. Is there any way to query such values? Conversion I can handle it through node application.

**First**

```
db.<collection>.find({_id:<id>}, {_id:0, <field>:1})
```

returns

```
{"startDate": Date("29906992800000") }
```

**Second**

```
db.<collection>.aggregate([{$match:{_id:<id>}, {$project:{_id:0, t:{$type:"<field>"}}}}])
```

returns

```
{"t": "string"}
```

Comment: '29906992800000' doesn't look like a date tbh, is this an accurate number? What are the bson types of both fields?

Comment: @AlexBlex `29906992800000` this is what exactly stored in the db. It is not 2 different fields. It's 2 different value in the same field

Comment: hmm, a field cannot have more than 1 value at a time. How does it look when you find this document as `db.<collection>.find({_id:<id>}, {_id:0, <field>:1})` and as `db.<collection>.aggregate([{$match:{_id:<id>}, {$project:{_id:0, t:{$type:"<field>"}}}}])` in mongo shell ?

Comment: @AlexBlex Updated my question with the result of these 2 queries

Comment: Sorry Prabhakaran, it makes no sense to me. Did you search the same _id, and did it in mongo shell? It's hard to believe it returns "Date" for values with type "string".

Comment: Even strange to me. It returns string

Comment: I would really appreciate if you isolate this document to a new collection `db.<col>.aggregate([{$match:{_id:<id>}, {$project:{_id:0, startDate:1}}}, {$out:"stackoverflow"}])`, export this collection with [mongodump](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump) and upload somewhere with public access. I'd like to reproduce. What version of the database and the shell you are using?

Comment: I mean, it's not normal behaviour. Whilst there is nothing strange if a document was inserted/updated manually (or at least without mongoose) with startDate as a string, I find it very confusing that the find query returns it as a Date.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for you efforts. I have updated the question that works. This may be useful to someone so left it open.

Comment: Ah, so it was robomongo, not stock shell. You should really post it as an answer an accept it rather than edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Alex I am posting as answer.

We have imported the data to MongoDB Compass, and used the normal sort method to filter out these dates and updated manually. Before I used Robo 3T may be that have some limitations.

[image]